# MYSQL limit returns unexpected results

Tags: php, sql, limit

```
<?php
$quuuu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products limit 9,15 ") or die("Query Error");
while($ffff=mysql_fetch_array($quuuu)){
    echo "<li><a href='view.php?id=" . $ffff['id'] . "'>" . $ffff['title'] . "</a></li>";
}
echo mysql_num_rows($quuuu);
?>
```

its should return (7),
and the result is (15)

Comment: If all else fails you could always [Read The Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)

Comment: "The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).

With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and **the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.** The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1): "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LIMIT use is wrong.

```
Syntax: limit start_at, amount_of_records
```

If you want 7 elements starting at 15th element, you should use

```
SELECT * from products limit 14, 7
```

Comment: That is a bit incorrect. The first value is the offset so for records 15-21 (7 records starting at 15) it would be `SELECT * from products limit 14, 7`...If that is what the OP wants, I was unclear so I just pointed out what the current query does.

Comment: You're right. Because the set of records starts at 0.

Answer (score 0):

See the doc, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html.

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.

So with your query,

> SELECT * FROM products limit 9,15

You are telling `mysql` to return fifteen rows starting at the tenth row. You are getting `15` from `echo mysql_num_rows($quuuu);` because there are 15 rows. Why do you expect `7` to be outputted?

Also note that the `mysql_` driver is depreciated, you should switch over to `PDO` or `mysqli`. They have a lot more useful features.

http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

> The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php